# How to set the cursor to hourglass when using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to change the cursor to an hourglass while doing some processing with d3.js.

I have tried this source:

```
var chart = d3.select("body")
.append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.attr("id","chart")
.attr("class","chart");
                    
chart.style('cursor','wait');
```

The code below supplied by Anko changes the cursor but raised another problem:
The change is not done until my function is done. But that is another question.

```
d3.select("body").style("cursor", "wait");
```

Comment: This will only change the cursor when you move it over the SVG. If you want the cursor to change everywhere, try setting this on the body of the document.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how to do that? I tried with     document.body.style.cursor  = 'wait'; 
but it didn't work.

Comment: @LarsL Try `d3.select("body").style("cursor", "wait");`.

Comment: @Anko Thanks for the code, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Anko: What browser do you use? I'm using chrome
Also, I try to set the hourglass with your code in the beginning of a function and restore the original cursor at the end of the function.

Comment: @LarsL I'm on Chromium. My steps: Open [D3 home page](http://d3js.org/). Open JS console. Run `d3.select("body").style("cursor", "wait")`. You can restore the original cursor look by calling `.style("cursor", "auto")`. [Here](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/cursor)'s a reference for the `cursor` CSS property. Still though, some of your elements might  have their own default cursors that override the one in your `<body>`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192900/wait-cursor-over-entire-html-page)'s a question about that.

Comment: @Anko Your code does work, if I not restore the cursor at the end of my function. E.i. it seems like the processing of the cursorchange is made after leaving my functon. Can the fact that the functio is called from a onmouseup event have something to do with it?

Comment: @LarsL I don't understand. Could you post a small example?

Comment: @Anko I have searched some more and the problem seems to be that js not is threaded but most browsers are. E.I the browser executes my function first, then is the cursor changed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495042/basic-javascript-loading-message-while-js-processing-completes

Comment: Yep, JS is pretty bad for resource-intensive computation for that reason. You could look into [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) or make a [request](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests) and do the work on a server. That's quite far from this question though -- maybe you should ask another or edit this one.