# How to make the cursor change in d3.js when I want?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, execution

This is a question related to [Basic Javascript loading message while js processing completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495042/basic-javascript-loading-message-while-js-processing-completes)

My main problem is that cursor not is changed before my two functions drawlegend() and display() are called, but changes after everthing has finnished. 
With the code as below where the restore of the cursor temporary commented out, I get the hourglass, but after everything has finnished.

How to get my cursor to change to an hourglass before my slow functions are called?

```
examplefunc()
{
   mini.append("text")
    .text(series[i].name)
    .attr("x",30)
    .attr("y",(15+(15*i)))
    .attr("stroke",(d3.rgb(192,192,192)))
    .attr("fill",(d3.rgb(192,192,192)))
    .attr("stroke-width",0)
    .style("font-size","12px")
    .attr("text-anchor","start")
    .attr("id","legend")
    .on('mouseup', legendclick);
}

//===== legend clicked
function legendclick()
{
   //--- get mouse pos
   var origin = d3.mouse(this);

   //---  get channel
   var ch=Math.floor((origin[1]-4)/15);

   //--- toggle active state
   if (series[ch].active==true)
      series[ch].active=false;
   else
      series[ch].active=true;

   setTimeout(setcursor("wait"),5);         
   drawlegend();
   display();
   //setTimeout(setcursor("default"),5); // temp removed to see any result at all
 }

//===== set cursor
function setcursor(cursor)
{
  d3.select("body").style("cursor", cursor);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that executing things in javascript, hangs your application. This means that only the eventual output is displayed on your screen. Thus, when you change the cursor to "wait" and after execution to "cursor", the javascript hasn't changed it, because the ui thread was busy calculating the things in the functions "drawlegend" and "display". However, I think when you execute the "drawlegend" and "display" asynchronous like

```
setTimeout(function () {
        drawLegend();
        display();
        setcursor("default");
}, 0);
```

then things should go like you want to.
Let me know if this works for you.

Extra info: on [this slideshare](https://web.archive.org/web/20210307123354/http://www.slideshare.net/clutchski/writing-asynchronous-javascript-101) (especially slide 5) is explained what your problem is.